# Why doesn't Join a Conference show up under my Gmail account in Trillian?

Tags: gmail, chat, jabber, xmpp, trillian

I read that Trillian supports the XMPP Conference feature and there is supposed to be a "Join a Conference" option when I click my account icon.  But when I click my Gmail icon, I don't see it.  I thought Gmail Talk supports XMPP.  Why doesn't it show up?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate XMPP account in the Trillian account manager, with the same Gmail email address and password.  Then, click the V (XMPP icon) then Join a Conference.

Even though Gmail Talk uses XMPP, Trillian does not expose this functionality through a "Gmail" account.